# Why does "Insert the diskette that contains the batch file and press any key when ready." message appear?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I just want to understand what is going on. I get the following message (English translation of Japanese message I got ... shown in the attached picture at the very end of this post):

> Insert the diskette that contains the batch file
> and press any key when ready.

To reproduce the message, here is what I did.

1. Create a batch file "**20201223**_test.bat" with the following
   content:

   > del /Q **20201223**_*.*
2. Place the batch file in a directory somewhere in **B:** drive
   (as a side note, **B:** is the name of an additional hard drive I've connected to my machine).
3. Execute the "20201223_test.bat" by double clicking for example.
   The message I am talking about should appear.

---

**Note:** I understand there is problem with the content and naming of the batch file to begin with but I was baffled by the message. This message doesn't occur when it is in **C:** drive. When it is in **C:** drive, it shows the following message instead because  "20201223_test.bat" has been deleted:

> バッチ ファイルが見つかりません。

which translates to the following in English:

> batch file could not be found

---

[image]

Comment: Is guess it's because windows assumes that drive b denotes a floppy disk drive. HDs start from c.

Comment: Agree with @daniu, in ancient times, A and B drives were used for floppy drives :)

Comment: There are people who think that it is a good idea to map a network resource (shared folder) or a USB connected storage media to driver letter `A` or `B` as there are never floppy drives with that driver letter connected to the motherboard of the computer. That is no good idea and now you know why. The drives `A:` and `B:` are floppy drives for Windows command processor `cmd.exe` independent on what these two drives are in real. Some commands are handled especially in error conditions different on drive is `A:` or `B:`. Therefore don't use `A:` and `B:` for something other than floppy drives.

Comment: @Mofi I now understand the message. The batch deletes itself and then ask for itself but since A: and B: drives are reserved for floppy drives ... instead of outputting the message "batch file could not be found", it outputs for "Insert the diskette that contains the batch file and press any key when ready."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A: and B: drives are reserved for floppies. If only 1 floppy is installed it appears as both A: and B: drive as Windows/Dos emulate it as two physical drives by promoting you to put in right floppy.

You should not have mapped them.